# Fill in the missing gap on this complex algebra problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't quite see how the sheet I am looking at has justified this step I assumed it was squaring and square rooting to remove the modulus signs but I can't work out the same result myself. Could anyone fill in the gap?

$$|(x-1)+i(y-1)|=4 \implies \sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}=4$$

Comment: It is simply the definition of the length of a vector on the complex plain. Nothing much to explain besides that. You can think of it as Pythagoras's theorem for measuring the hypotenuse of a right triangle.

Comment: Ah got ya thanks buddy.